# AppCompat - styling using v14 folder performance

Tags: android, performance, android-appcompat

Is there a performance difference in these two methods of implementing AppCompat styles? Is one method better than the other?

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sunshine_blue_500</item>
    <item name="background">@color/sunshine_blue_500</item>
</style>
```

---------vs--------------------

**values-v14/styles.xml**

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sunshine_blue_500</item>
</style>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/sunshine_blue_500</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The v-14 double folder method is better, or you'll get an error if the values/styles.xml contains a namespace that isn't accessible by the min API level